# RegEx to determine if string is score

Tags: php, regex

Good Evening,

I'm in the process of attempting to parse large amounts of data using php.  I'm working through discovering what is contained within the data.  If I'm given a string such as

> Atlante 0-1 Toluca

I'd like to use a RegEx pattern to detect if the string contains #-#, regardless of what is before or after the #-#.

Scores, in theory could be anything from 0-0 -> 0-100.

Any help creating this pattern is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: RegEx isn't that hard to learn. Have you tried to figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match a number, followed immediately by a hyphen, followed immediately by another number, allows for multi-digit numbers, and has groups to give you each of the scores.

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/', $string, $match);
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Works perfect.  +1 for adding the groups, a feature I didn't expect but greatly appreciate.